# I get nested tables, but I need separated tables (Netoffice,Word)

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, ms-word, netoffice

I wrote a WPF-Application to print a word documents with some tables in it, it works, but I get nested tables instead of separated tables.

I was looking at different post, but they all did not work quite well e.g.:

- [VB version](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?505967-RESOLVED-Text-after-Table-%28Word%29)
- [.NET 4.5, but I need .NET 4.0 (by the way it did not solve my problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718044/how-to-add-items-one-at-a-time-to-to-a-new-line-a-word-document-using-word-inter)
- [insertParagraphAfter()](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/a25ba73f-324d-4926-93b5-89460f77621d/)

As well, as I tried to record a macro with word, which gave me

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
```

and I turned this into:

```
wordApplication.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 1);
```

or even:

```
wordApplication.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 11);
```

This is the beginning of my originally code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using NetOffice;
using Word = NetOffice.WordApi;
using NetOffice.WordApi.Enums;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
...
Word.Application wordApplication ...
Word.Document newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add();
```

This is the first table:

```
        Word.Table table = newDocument.Tables.Add(wordApplication.Selection.Range, 6, 2);

        // insert some text into the cells
        table.Cell(1, 1).Select();
        wordApplication.Selection.TypeText("...");
...
```

This is the second table, but the text goes into the last cell of my first table(last cell):

```
            Word.Table tableSchool = newDocument.Tables.Add(wordApplication.Selection.Range, 4, 2, WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord9TableBehavior);
        tableSchool.Cell(1, 1).Select();
        wordApplication.Selection.TypeText("...");
...
```

**updated. 17 th june, 9 p.m**

I found something,which puts the cursor outsisde of the table, but it is at the begining of the file, this shouldn't be:

```
    wordApplication.Selection.GoToNext(WdGoToItem.wdGoToSection);
    wordApplication.Selection.TypeText("GoToNext");
```

**updated. 17 th june, 9:30 p.m**

Using "InsertAfter" works, depending on where I put this statement, but this still does not solve my problem.

```
    wordApplication.Selection.Range.InsertAfter("test2");

    Word.Table table = newDocument.Tables.Add(wordApplication.Selection.Range, 4, 2, WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord9TableBehavior);
```

This should be adjusted "wordApplication.Selection.Range" to some kind of "InsertAfter", combining the two things I found out.

**updated 18.06 07:30 a.m**

If I use this, I get a "ComException"(macro recorder showed me this):

```
wordApplication.Selection.MoveRight(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
        wordApplication.Selection.TypeParagraph();
```

**updated 18.06 07:45 a.m**

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171623/how-to-paste-table-to-the-end-of-a-ms-word-document-using-c-sharp), which is pretty close to my aim(,but it replaces the last cell of the previous table):

```
            wordApplication.Selection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory, WdMovementType.wdExtend);
        wordApplication.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);
```

Thanks in advance :)